# Google map API and MD5?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use Google map in my android application. How can I get The API key after having the MD5 code? 
Is it necessary, or i can take a simple api from the developer site?

Comment: You have to Enable Google Android Map V2 from google APi console and after that generate a key from Command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://code.google.com/apis/console/ to register and select google map android and turn on.

Then register your SHA1 finger print.As you mentioned MD5 finger print.You should not use MD5. use SHA1 finger print along with package name and you will get key.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this properly and get what you want....

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: aha I can obtain Api key from API console , but when need i "Displaying the debug certificate fingerprint"

Comment: but if you have got your api key then u have to get ur fingerprint of SHA-1